# Regular expression to name

Tags: jquery, regex

Condition for regular expression is

1. Only letter
2. space is allowed only after 2 charecter is entered
3. only one space is allowed not more then one, please help me I am new to jQuery

Now I am using this one but it not works:

```
$('.name').keyup(function() {  
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g,'');    
});
```

Comment: By "charecter" do you mean "letter"? _Everything_ you type is a character. Are you trying to say that only upper- or lowercase letters and spaces are allowed, but spaces are only allowed if there are at least two letters at the start of the string? (Whatever your requirement, note that a `keyup` handler is not enough on its own given that the user can drag'n'drop or cut/paste/delete with the mouse or Edit menu.)

Comment: Note also that changing the content of a field that the user is typing in will annoy them, especially if they're trying to edit at the start of the field and the code keeps moving the cursor. I'd suggest testing the format when they leave the field and either show an error message or remove the invalid characters at that point.

Comment: what does being new to jQuery have to do with regex? Why didn't you tag this with `regex` tag?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you'll need to use multiple regex's in order to get the results that you want.  Also, I agree with @nnnnnn that users will find auto-replacing annoying.

Here is a solution that works though I'm guessing it could be optimized:

```
$( function() { 
    $('#test').keyup(function(){
        //Remove all characters except letters and whitespace
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z\s]/g,'');
        //Replace all instance of One or more whitespaces with a space
        this.value = this.value.replace(/\s+/g,' ');
        //Replace a space that happens after zero or one characters
        this.value = this.value.replace(/^([a-zA-Z]{0,1})(\s)([a-zA-Z]+)/,'$1$3');
        //Replaces any spaces that occur after the first space
        this.value = this.value.replace(/^([a-zA-Z]{2,})(\s+)([a-zA-Z]+)(\s+)/,'$1$2$3');
    });
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle that demonstrates it working. http://jsfiddle.net/mattpaulsen/sSUhn/3/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regular expression that will grab the smallest substring that still matches your requirements.

```
var reg = /[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*[ ]?[A-Za-z]*/;
```

You can validate the input of the username by comparing it returned substring with the original string. I'll created a jsFiddle that did so here: http://jsfiddle.net/cjC5k/